# <nested:hidden> field missing id

Tags: java, struts

I'm trying to define a id of a `<nested:hidden` filed in struts 1, but with styleId i receive a error:

my code looks something like this:

```
<nested:iterate id="otherPayList" name="myPayListForm" property="otherPayList"  indexId="rowIndex">

<nested:hidden property="rowStatus"/>

.......
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`<nested:iterate>`](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#nested%3aiterate) tag is an extension for [`<logic:iterate>`](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#logic%3aiterate).

The *property* of `<nested:hidden>` is:

> the name of the corresponding bean
>   property if value is not specified.
>   The corresponding bean property (if
>   any) must be of type String.

The reason you have an error is because Struts can't find a bean of typed to name `rowStatus` (in the `<nested:hidden>` tag). You have not specified what errors Struts is throwing (ie, exception logs) so I'm working on what you've given.

---

If I understand you properly,

you want to do this (provided it's nested in the `<nested:iterate>` tag).

```
<nested:hidden name="otherPayList" property="rowStatus" />
```

---

For `<nested:hidden>` tag, there is no attribute called `id` and setting the id to `styleId` won't work as styleId looks for a CSS declaration with id matching styleId (i.e. it will look for a css, if `styleId="thatId"` declared `#thatId { }`).

See Struts Documentation on [`nested.tld`](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#struts-nested.tld)

Comment: thanks for your quick repply but i've set the bean name '<c:set var="rowCounter" value="0"/>'. the question is how to pun an ID to the '<nested:hidden'?

Comment: `rowCounter`? where does `rowStatus` come from?

Comment: rowStatus come from otherPayList witch is a list of objects

Comment: yes it's ok but how I will retrieve this value in javascript ? document.getElementById("?")

Comment: So i have a '<nested:hidden' filed. What i want is to retrieve his value in javascript with the follwoing command document.getElementById. But currently i'm unable to set the id of the '<nested:hidden' filed. How can i set the id value ?

Comment: You can't set an id on Struts `nested:hidden` and don't use `styleId` either. See my updated post.